# how to show progress dialog as background of button after clicking it?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a button in my application. I would like to a show progress dialog replacing the button, after clicking it.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

On button click:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setVisibility(View.GONE)
findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the button and the progress bar at the same location through layout xml and set 
the progress bar's visibility as `GONE`.

Now in the `onClick()` method of button, set

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE)
progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```